# IIS cgi: what's the meaning of "%s" %s

Tags: iis-6, cgi, v8cgi

I am fiddling a bit with v8cgi on an IIS6 server. Does anyone know what the `"%s" %s` parameters in a (cgi) service mapping and application path actually mean/do? I really can't find anything on that on the internet. Additionaly, if someone knows, is there a way to get v8cgi running using iis fastcgi extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [here](http://www.xav.com/perl/faq/Windows/ActivePerl-Winfaq6.html)

> To run Perl as a CGI application, type the full path to Perl.EXE followed by %s %s. When a script is executed, the first %s will be replaced by the full path to the script, and the second %s will be replaced by the script parameters.

They did not include quotes around the first `%s` but they should be there in case there are spaces in the filename.